# Replacing values in a column using a named list

Tags: r

Let's say one of the columns in my dataframe refers to the name of a city. The city names are expressed as "longformA", "longformB", and I'd like to replace them all with "shrtfrmA", "shrtfrmB". Each "longform" name has an associated "shrtfrm" name with which it should be replaced.

I've got a solution involving a named list and purrr bouncing around in my head, but I can't quite conceptualize it. The named list would have this structure:

```
city_names_short <- list("ANA" = "Anaheim", "BOS" = "Boston")
```

And so on, and so forth.

```
example_df$city[example_df$city == "Anaheim"] <- "ANA"
example_df$city[example_df$city == "Boston"] <- "BOS"
```

I could of course replace them one by one, as per the above, but I'd like to be a little more elegant.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest unlisting your list to a named vector and then using `match` to create the shortform names:

```
city_names_short <- unlist(city_names_short)
df$shortname <- names(city_names_short)[match(df$city, city_names_short)]
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

You can loop over your city column using `sapply`:

```
df$city <- sapply(df$city, function(city) { 
    names(city_names_short)[city_names_short == city] 
})
```

The function in `sapply` finds the name (i.e. the shortened city name) of the list item that matches each city name.

**Method 2**

You can create a map by inverting the `city_names_short` list:

```
city_map <- names(city_names_short)
names(city_map) <- city_names_short
df$city <- city_map[df$city]
```

Comment: I believe Method 2, line 1, should be `setNames()`  not `names()`

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `setNames` in base R:

```
map = setNames(c("ANA","BOS"),c("Anaheim","Boston"))
df$city_short = map[df$city_long]
```